# Why isn't a returned cell nil in cellForRowAtIndexPath in Apple's TheElements example?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I know this question may seem a bit odd, but I was looking at the Apple example, TheElements, and noticed that their implementation of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` doesn't even check if the dequeued cell is nil.

If you are just getting the latest version of TheElements example, that is not the one I'm referring to. You will have to replace `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` with the older version, which is just `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`.

**Here is why I expect the initial dequeued cell to be nil:**
From the Apple docs for `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`...
*This method dequeues an existing cell if one is available or creates a new one using the class or nib file you previously registered. If no cell is available for reuse and you did not register a class or nib file, this method returns nil.*

However, I ran it through the debugger, and found that the first time that the method is called, the returned cell has a value.

Whereas in my humble implementation of a `UIViewController`, the dequeued cells are initially nil, until they are recycled, as the Apple docs have explained.

**Edit**

After receiving answers and checking them out, the reason that no nil cells are dequeued is clear: the example uses a storyboard in which the table view controller contains a prototype cell.

This is my implementation, which checks if a cell is nil.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [_tableModel objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

And, this is the implementation from the example, TheElements:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    AtomicElementTableViewCell *cell =
        (AtomicElementTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AtomicElementTableViewCell"];

    // set the element for this cell as specified by the datasource. The atomicElementForIndexPath: is declared
    // as part of the ElementsDataSource Protocol and will return the appropriate element for the index row
    //
    cell.element = [self atomicElementForIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Whereas in my humble implementation of a UIViewController, the dequeued cells are initially nil, until they are recycled

So, a little history.

- In **iOS 4** and before, you called `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` to get your cells. The initial cells were all nil, until you had a pile big enough to start recycling them. Thus you needed to check for nil and create the initial pile of cells yourself.

  That is what *you* are doing.
- In **iOS 5**, storyboards were introduced. One big advantage of using the storyboard was that it could function as the source of cells. Thus, `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`, if used with an identifier that matched the identifier in the storyboard, would *never* return nil.

  That is what *The Elements* is doing in the code you cite.
- In **iOS 6** came `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`. This allowed the thing the storyboard did in iOS 5 to happen *always*. By registering the cell class or nib to tie it to the identifier, *or* by matching the cell identifier with the identifier in the storyboard, you configure the table so that, when you call  `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`, *the table* generates the new cell if a new one is needed. Thus, the cell is never nil.

  That is what you *should* be doing. You register UITableViewCell with the table, for your cell identifier; then you call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` with that cell identifier, and behold, the cell will never be nil.

By the way, we are now at iOS 8. So what you are doing is not merely outmoded - it is outmoded by four generations.

Comment: And see the discussion in my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch21.html#_registering_a_cell_class

Answer (score 0):

You can learn the following two methods.

```
- (void)registerNib:(UINib *)nib forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
- (void)registerClass:(Class)cellClass forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
```

When using a storyboard, tableview will register a nib or sth like a nib with a special identifier, you can also custom a identifier in the cell's xib fragment.

If you create your tableview using code, you can register a cell class in the vc's viewDidLoad method.

then you can always dequeue a cell with your registered identifier in the tableview's callback.

Comment: You can take a look at my demo, https://github.com/lovesunstar/stkitdemo/blob/master/STKitDemo/Classes/BaseUI/STAlertView.m   

in the line 112 and line 195. You'll know how to use it to register a cell.

Comment: If you create from the storyboard, you just set the identifier for your cell, and the tableview will register cell automatically.

Comment: I have told you that, if the tableview is created by the storyboard, then tableview will automatically register cell with the dest identifier in the cell's storyboard fragment.

Comment: maybe sometimes someone vote down is because they think it's not a good question, or the way you asked is not good or the question is not clear. not always means it's useless

Comment: Yes, thank you. After I saw the storyboard in the example, I realized what you were talking about. I was not using xib or storyboards, but the Elements example did have a prototyped cell in their storyboard.